# Azure web app deployed to tmp folder instead of wwwroot

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I have been deploying my Django Python Web app on Azure App Service for a few hundred times now.

Recently, i made a small change in the html file and push it but the deployment went differently.

Instead of deploying the app in `home/site/wwwroot/`, Oryx deployed it to a `tmp` folder. (See the screenshot)

I'm confused over why this happened. I didn't change ANY settings or configuration and my web app ended up in a `tmp` folder.

Anyone knows what happened here and how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was the issue. There was a change in the Python build process on Azure App Services. The details can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/KuduLite/wiki/Python-Build-Changes).

I quote from the link above.

> ### Change
>
> Python build and runtime workflow is changing for the apps built on
> App Service.
>
> ### Current build process
>
> The app builds are carried out in a build container/agent by a Build
> System called Oryx. This container produces artifacts which are stored
> on an NFS volume and later run by a Runtime container defined by the
> user(eg: Python 3.8).
>
> Oryx running in the Build Agent installs the dependencies listed in
> requirements.txt into a virtual environment named antenv. This build
> is carried out in a local build directory. This virtual environment
> produced by the above build is compressed and extracted by the runtime
> at the root of the container to enable the users to have an optimal
> build and startup time.
>
> This caused a problem where the Virtual Environment could not resolve
> certain app dependencies. The reason for this is that during the
> creation of the Virtual Environment pip hardcodes certain paths for
> dependencies. Since, the builds are carried out in an Build Container
> and Run on a Runtime container at a different path, this causes a
> mismatch between the directory structure for the virtual environment.
>
> ### Change/New Build+Runtime Process
>
> The build workflow remains the same with respect to the use of a
> temporary build directory as described above. But now the whole app
> output(including the Virtual Environment) is compressed into a tarball
> and stored at /home/site/wwwroot with a manifest file
> oryx-manifest.toml. This manifest file describes how the build was
> carried out in the build container. The runtime container on startup
> reads this manifest and recreates a local copy of the folder structure
> on every instance. This change also ensures that the runtime during
> the app startup will already have the virtual environment activated
> and users can run commands like migrate without the need to activate
> the environment.
>
> **As a part of this change, the app would no longer run from
> /home/site/wwwroot but would have a dynamic runtime directory. This
> path can be retrieved by using the variable $APP_PATH.**

If this change broke your app, your only option is to change your file path. There's nothing you can do to stop Azure App Service from running your Django app from `tmp`.

EDIT:
I opened an issue with the Azure team on this and they are working to roll back the changes. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/ImageBuilder/issues/87)

EDIT:
[Latest update](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/ImageBuilder/issues/87#issuecomment-751838978) (20201229)

> We are in the process of reverting to the old deployment behavior
> across all regions. The new behavior would be an opt-in after this
> fix, we would send out notifications and give ample time to make
> changes when we change the default behavior.
>
> You could pin to the old version by adding an app setting:
> KUDU_BUILD_VERSION=0.0.1 -> This would ensure the build behavior
> remains the same even when we change default behavior after the
> notification.
>
> To try the new version, you can add the app setting:
> KUDU_BUILD_VERSION=1.0.0.
>
> Please share your app names directly or indirectly if you are still
> experiencing the problem and we can investigate further

Comment: Thank you for raising this issue with Azure.  The new tmp folder deployment process has broken my flask app as well.

Answer (score 1):

**It is suggested to make the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT= FALSE`.**

For more details, you can refer to this post([Azure App Service Getting error while deploying REACT JS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846235/azure-app-service-getting-error-while-deploying-react-js-application)).

I read his post carefully and did not find the cause of this problem. If you are interested, you can raise a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for making an attempt to help me, really appreciate it. Turns out the issue is that Azure made some change to the python build process. I have answered my own question. Once again, thanks for reply and helping out :)

Comment: @snowflake How to fix it, you can add the way in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This post was a saver for me. Thanks for this. MS did a poor job updating folks on this change. It really bit us and was a wild goose chase until I ran into this. After I read this, it took very little time to pull things together and there's a few lessons learned I'll share as a thanks and in hopes others won't go through this pain.

1. this change happened on 3/1/21 but nothing will break until you do a deployment post that date. All will continue to work fine until then. That's when you'll see inexplicable things going on because MS is using a TAR file strategy and visualizing things, etc. BUT, these processes will NOT change your current setup nor will it delete anything. All creating a mess! So, if, for example, you look at wwwroot from bash or ftp, no files will change/update no matter how many times you redeploy. So, if you've learned about this rather radical change before a planned deployment, clean things up; then move to a CI/CD model and leverage GitHub is my recommendation, deleting everything beforehand - sort of a "start fresh" approach. Do that, and you're good to go. Else, you'll be chasing ghosts if you've already deployed. I was the later case and that just meant a redo from scratch after many headaches.
2. if you have any ref'd resources that are outside of you Git repo, $APP_PATH is key and while this is all virtual now, using "/home" as the user friendly way to point at you app path is the key tidbit. $APP_PATH is useful for Bash and FTP work. "/home" for code. Also NOTE, ONLY things saved under /home will persist. In my case, I moved my folder from wwwroot to /home/ and a slight change in code (added "/home/" was all that was needed. And using an app variable is probably better coding practice :)
3. Once you setup CI/CD, that rocks, so that's amazing. Make a code change, get an email things have changed and go monitor on GitHub the build/deploy process. If it turns "red", fix it; check it in; watch and wait.

Final point on #3. I know you can work around this with a variable. My suggestion is NOT to do that. MS' reasons for this change are way better than their ability to communicate it out. It's a good idea and works very well. I'm using a rather complex ML model whose performance improved by about 10-15%. Maybe that's luck, but it made me a believer in this change.

Just hope MS' learned how to keep us informed better next time :)

HTH.