# Azure web app intermittently copying code from tmp to home

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, oryx

I am deploying a Django appication to a Azure Web App via Github Actions. The code is consistently deployed to the tmp folder but is not always copied to wwwroot, even though Oryx deployment logs state that the contents are copied. What causes this intermittent behaviour?

```
Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  python: 3.8.12

Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8da59cae1f18fde'.

Copying files to the intermediate directory...
Done in 0 sec(s).

Source directory     : /tmp/8da59cae1f18fde
Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot

Python Version: /opt/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8
Creating directory for command manifest file if it doesnot exist
Removing existing manifest file
Python Virtual Environment: antenv
Creating virtual environment...
Activating virtual environment...
Running pip install...

Content in source directory is a Django app
Running collectstatic...
Done in 18 sec(s).
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/tmp/_preCompressedDestinationDir'...
Done in 31 sec(s).
Compressing content of directory '/tmp/_preCompressedDestinationDir'...
Copied the compressed output to '/home/site/wwwroot'

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.

Done in 244 sec(s).
```

Comment: Please refer [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321862/azure-web-app-deployed-to-tmp-folder-instead-of-wwwroot) in SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure web app deployed to tmp folder instead of wwwroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321862/azure-web-app-deployed-to-tmp-folder-instead-of-wwwroot)

Comment: Thanks, but it did not lead to a solution for me unfortunately. I have updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

**For others that may be struggling with this same issue, specifically with Django applications, I have landed on the following workaround:**

After learning more about how Oryx build actually works, I now understand that the code IS copied to wwwroot - but as a tarball. The code is then extracted to tmp and executed in this folder. This causes a challenge running django migrations as the migration folder is not persistent at the location where the code is run from, i.e. you are not able to run migrations automatically from the tmp folder (because, assuming you are not putting your migrations in source control, there is no migration history here.) *and* you are not able to run migrations from wwwroot (because the new code only exists in the tarball). So, in order to persist migration history you will need to:

1. Extract output.tar.gz in its entirety to wwwroot and overwrite existing files.
   **OR**
2. Do 1. ONCE in order to get your project structure ready to perform migrations in wwwroot, and after this copy *only* the files needed to detect database changes (in my case settings.py, forms.py, models.py and admin.py) from tmp to wwwroot. This can be done automatically by editing the startup command.