# Updated index.html not showing in browser

Tags: python, azure, flask

I have a very simple python Flask app. It is just an app.py and a templates/index.html. It is deployed in Azure. The problem is that when I make changes to the index.html and re-deploy it, the browser still loads the old one although I can see the new index.html on the server. I have tried Azure Web App Service stop/start to no success.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you be more clear where you deployed it and how? 
Azure App Services, Static Web Apps, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is an Azure Web App Service. It was deployed automatically since it is connected to github for auto-deployment. Once I committed the change to the index.html file, a deployment was initiated and completed successfully.

Comment: If the Answer below doesn't solve your problem. Can you please also post your deployment pipeline.

Comment: @JulianHüppauff I found a solution by following the instructions in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321862/azure-web-app-deployed-to-tmp-folder-instead-of-wwwroot) although my case is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably still cached by your browser. Try to reload the site without cache (Different for every browser and OS - shift+f5 windows, cmd+r mac etc., ...).

You can set an HTTP-Header to control how long files are cached.
I'd recommend using the `@app.after_request` decorator.

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.cache_control.max_age = 300  # set this to 0 to force a reload every time
    return response
```

I hope that helps. If not, please provide a little bit more code.

Comment: Thanks @bitflip for your suggestion. It did not work for me as the problem was Azure issue. I tried a workaround suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321862/azure-web-app-deployed-to-tmp-folder-instead-of-wwwroot) and that fixed the issue for me.