# Deploy a Python Flask App on Azure - Env Recreated and Packages Reinstalled Every time

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

Why does deploying updates a python Flask app to Azure Web App Service re-create the app virtual environment and reinstalls every required package? This takes a very long time and is really not needed if I am only updating a .html file or .py file without importing any new package.

Is there a way to deploy updates to my python app without this un-necessary step? It takes approximately 22 minutes to do a simple deployment this way :(

.
.

Comment: Does your startup command script contain the commands for the installation process?

Comment: @SoySolisCarlos I did not create any startup script. I just followed the same steps in the QuickStart article for python Flask app for Azure [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cvscode-aztools%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli)

Comment: I found A solution by following instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321862/azure-web-app-deployed-to-tmp-folder-instead-of-wwwroot) and updating the files via SFTP