# IIS Application pool stops responding

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

I have a web application, developed with Visual Studio 2019, targeting .Net Framework 4.8 and using an Angular front end. In production, using IIS 10, after running without problems for well over two weeks, the application just stopped responding, requiring recycling of the application pool. We are struggling to figure out why.

In the application error logs, I found a lot of the following entries (this is just one example):

> 2022-06-03 08:49:05.300 -05:00 [ERR] Failed writing message. Aborting
> connection. System.InvalidOperationException: Writing is not allowed
> after writer was completed.    at
> System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetMemory(Int32 sizeHint)    at
> System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeWriter.GetSpan(Int32 sizeHint)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeWriter.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext.d__49.MoveNext()
> 2022-06-03 08:49:06.643 -05:00 [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than
> ""00:00:01"" at ""2022-06-03T13:49:06.6435092+00:00"". 2022-06-03
> 08:49:07.955 -05:00 [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:07.9557024+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:09.158 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:09.1585443+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:10.267 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:10.2676601+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:11.283 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:11.2830451+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:12.298 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:12.2984324+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:13.313 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:13.3138198+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:14.329 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:14.3292071+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:15.344 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:15.3445944+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:16.359 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:16.3599817+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:17.375 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:17.3753694+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:18.390 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:18.3907585+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:19.406 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:19.4061440+00:00"". 2022-06-03 08:49:20.421 -05:00
> [WRN] Heartbeat took longer than ""00:00:01"" at
> ""2022-06-03T13:49:20.4215310+00:00"".

I did some research on the Signal R error (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR (1.1.0)), and found it reported by multiple people here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6701
No solution is offered, but one person commented that it may be  “a benign error”.
I don’t know either the cause of it, or whether it is serious.

Regarding the Heartbeat warning messages, my research suggests that they are caused because the CPU on the server is overworked.
See, for example:[How to resolve Heartbeat took longer than "00:00:01" failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645437/how-to-resolve-heartbeat-took-longer-than-000001-failure).

However, CPU monitoring shows that CPU usage never exceeded 20% at the time of the incident.

No relevant errors in IIS logs or Event Viewer logs.

Comment: You are running ASP.NET Core SignalR on .NET Framework and that cannot be any worse. To resolve, either you stick to the legacy ASP.NET 4.x SignalR on .NET Framework, or completely upgrade to ASP.NET Core + .NET Core. I don't think there is any middle ground.

Comment: Until after .net core 2.1, it was fine to run .net core on top of the .net framework. It was an out of the box option in Visual Studio. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865054/why-use-the-full-net-framework-with-asp-net-core  We have been running this for years without seeing these errors.

Comment: But time is your enemy, and all ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework versions are end of life, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

Comment: `after running without problems for well over two weeks` When the problem occurs, did the server make some changes such as automatic system upgrades or automatic patch updates?

Comment: @BruceZhang I don't know. I will ask our infrastructure person. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @BruceZhang I guess the answer is no. The last Windows Update on this server was installed on 4/2/2022

Comment: If so, I think it is necessary to use failed request tracing check what happen when the issue occur. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis However, if it is caused by network, network monitor is a better tool to troubleshoot this issue.